# Handling orElseThrow

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, throws

My method looks like this

```
public EP updateEP(long id, EP eP) {
        EE eE = eRepo.findById(id).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
        //some code
    }
```

and my test method looks like this

```
    @Test
    public void testUpdateEWhenEExists() {
        long id = 1l;
        EE eE = new EE();
        eE.setPosId(1l);
        eE.setPosName("pos");
        EPE ePE = new EPE();
        ePE.setEId(id);
     when(eRepo.findById(id).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new)).thenReturn(eE);
        //some code
    }
```

And it always throw `EntityNotFoundException`.I want to be returned to me eE instead of `EntityNotFoundException`

**EDIT**

```
    @Test
    public void testUpdateEPWhenEExists() {
        long id = 1l;
        EE eE = new E();
        eE.setPositionId(1l);
        eE.setPosName("pos");
        EPE ePE = new EPE();
        ePE.setEId(id);

        when(eRepo.findById(id)).thenReturn(Optional.of(eE));
    
    }
```

In this case error is

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
EPE cannot be returned by findById()
findById() should return Optional
```

Comment: `when(eRepo.findById(id)).thenReturn(eE)` should do the trick

Comment: Then i have to lie down in ```thenReturn``` ```Optional.of(eE)``` and it doesn`t help me.

Comment: What do you mean you have to lie down? EDIT: nevermind, I see what you mean, then just return an `Option.of(eE)`

Comment: I mean lie dowm = put in

Comment: Yeah, I understood just after I posted my comment, see the edited version.

Comment: Could you see my comment on the answer below, I tried the same advice)

Comment: How are `eRepo` in the first snippet and `eRepository` in the test declared, respectively? (i.e., what type are they)

Comment: Their type is ERepo

Comment: thanks, your advice helped. The problem was a typo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code sample you've provided it seems that eRepo.findById(id) returns an Optional.

```
eRepo.findById(id).orElseThrow(...)
```

receives that Optional and basically checks, if the Optional is empty. If not, it returns the instance of EE, otherwise it throws the specified exception.

In your test there is no need to call

```
orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new)
```

because you're explicitly mocking the behaviour of findById.
Just do it like that:

```
when(eRepo.findById(id)).thenReturn(Optional.of(eE));
```

Comment: I did as you said and this is the result ```org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
EPE cannot be returned by findById()
findById() should return Optional```

Comment: please provide code snippets from your repository and your test. It seems that you try to return Optional.of(ePE) instead of Optional.of(eE);

Comment: I need the full classes in an example because I can't see what you're trying to do exactly. 
And please don't modify the original question, because all comments and answers won't match the question after that. Just add a new answer with your changed code samples.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this to help anyone find this quicker.  I needed to assert the message and condition for the exception in a .orElseThrow() from an JPA repository.  The normal case is obvious to return Optional.of(someDataYouAlreadyMockedUp), but to get the exception , the repository stream must get a null (Empty) so use Optional.empty() ...

In my code I have

```
    License license = licenseRepository.findById(licenseId).orElseThrow(() ->
        new BadRequest("License " + licenseId + " not found."));
```

To test and assert the value in the Test I mock it like this:

```
when(licenseRepository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.empty());
```

And then call and assert like this:

```
 try {
      SomeDto result = someService.getSomeStuffByLicenseId(1L);
      fail("should have already thrown exception here!");
 }catch (BadRequest br) {
      assertEquals("License 1 not found", br.getMessage());
 }
```